# Automate Mann Whitney U test for huge dataset

Tags: r

I am an R newby, and I apologize in advance if the question is too trivial for you people, but I'm in all over my head.

While trying to learn R, I found myself faced with the problem of creating a repeat loop to perform Mann Whitney U test group 1 vs group 2 for multiple variables, one by one. Here below, an example. 
(https://i.redd.it/2c0429k4y3y21.png)

Even though I can perform the test one variable by one variable, from A to Z, in the real data I am testing I have over 10000 variables, hence I must find a way to 1) automate the test; 2) generate a file containing all the resulting p-values.

Would somebody be so kind to help me out with the task? I'm more than willing to spend as much time as I need to learn how to code in R, but I need a little nudge on this.

Thanks

Comment: What pairs of variables are you trying to test?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. It is unclear to me how your test related to your data. Do you want to test the values in all `Anatomy`, `Astronomy` etc. columns for the groups in `Sex`? Also it would be easier to answer the question if we would have a snippet of your data to play with, which you can create by posting the output of `dput(head(your_data))`.

Comment: Could you produce the data? Take your data, subset it and then use `dput` around the dataname as @teunbrand has suggested

Comment: Thanks for the lame description of my problem. What I intend to do is to test two groups (Mutant vs Wildtype) to find difference in the expression level of certain genes. The output of dput(head()) is the following

Comment: structure(list(genotype = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Mutant", 
"Wildtype"), class = "factor"), X312 = c(0, 0, 9.927911044, 7.604660497, 
0, 8.469434699), X1.Sep = c(9.296165425, 7.994991396, 10.3226941, 
10.59396298, 10.2554214, 7.963356173), X2.Sep = c(12.0207487, 
10.92364072, 11.22504751, 11.2077482, 11.91886469, 11.64801165
), X1.Dec = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X128up = c(8.051389852, 
8.437100325, 2.9382856, 9.05631996, 0, 8.993819702), X140up = c(7.859521468, 
7.638131579, 0, 8.567090791, 8.7672994, 10.219634)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Hi, did you get it to work? If you're still having issues pertaining to this question please let us know. If you feel your question got resolved, please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

As the data you supplied only had one factor level, I added three "Wildtypes" to make the code work.

```
gen <- structure(list(genotype=structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
    .Label=c("Mutant", "Wildtype"), class="factor"), X312=c(0, 0, 9.927911044,
    7.604660497, 0, 8.469434699), X1.Sep=c(9.296165425, 7.994991396, 10.3226941,
    10.59396298, 10.2554214, 7.963356173), X2.Sep=c(12.0207487, 10.92364072,
    11.22504751, 11.2077482, 11.91886469, 11.64801165), X1.Dec=c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L), X128up=c(8.051389852, 8.437100325, 2.9382856, 9.05631996, 0, 8.993819702),
    X140up=c(7.859521468, 7.638131579, 0, 8.567090791, 8.7672994, 10.219634)),
    row.names=c(NA, 6L), class="data.frame")


gen[1:3, 1] <- factor(rep(2, 3), label="Wildtype")
```

As we can perform the Mann Whitney U test on one column like so:

```
# for column 6
wilcox.test(gen[gen$genotype == "Mutant", 6], 
            gen[gen$genotype == "Wildtype", 6], exact=FALSE)$p.val
```

we can perform it on all the columns by simply looping over the column indices (excluding the first), using `sapply()`, like so:

```
sapply(2:ncol(gen), 
  function(x) {
      wilcox.test(gen[gen$genotype == "Mutant", x], 
                  gen[gen$genotype == "Wildtype", x], exact=FALSE)$p.val
  }
)
# [1] 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000     NaN 0.66252 0.08085
```